# Restore from backup causes app crash

Tags: ios, core-data

I've been struggling with Core Data for 3 days now and I'm only going backwards. I had to restore my entire project from a backup and now I get this:

```
2014-01-06 14:47:45.911 MyClub[1980:5003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't merge models with two different entities named 'SuperGroups''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101e70795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101bd3991 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreData                            0x00000001000fba1d +[NSManagedObjectModel modelByMergingModels:] + 3357
    3   CoreData                            0x00000001000b8e49 +[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:] + 521
    4   MyClub                              0x0000000100008499 -[AppDelegate managedObjectModel] + 105
    5   MyClub                              0x00000001000085fa -[AppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] + 266
    6   MyClub                              0x000000010000836c -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext] + 92
    7   MyClub                              0x000000010000b112 __38-[MyDownloader populateSuperGroupList]_block_invoke + 1058
    8   CFNetwork                           0x000000010273240e __50-[__NSCFLocalDownloadTask _private_fileCompletion]_block_invoke227 + 83
    9   Foundation                          0x00000001017fc19b -[NSBlockOperation main] + 75
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010184a844 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 623
    11  Foundation                          0x000000010184c71b __NSOQSchedule_f + 64
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102d4e6fd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102d3de37 _dispatch_queue_drain + 481
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102d3dbfc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 112
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102d3eb14 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 257
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102d3ed65 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001030f8ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001030fbfb9 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

What do I do (other than swear loudly and profusely at Core Data, which I've already tried multiple times)?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the application from Simulator or Phone and re-run it? It appears your CoreData model has changed between the different versions.

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. If you post this as a soultion, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you make a change to the Core Data's Object Model you have to make sure you get rid of the application on your simulator/phone. The model on the device must match the model in your code or you will get an error.

There is a process in place that will allow you to technically have two seperate models so that when you say put an update in to the app store you can do it without users having to delete all their data. If you ever need this I would look into "Core Data Versioning".

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have two managed object models in your project (Both have an entity in them named SuperGroups). Try loading a specific one via its URL, or deleting the duplicate from your project.